# What happens after netdev_open?

Tags: linux-kernel, wireless, device-driver

I'm trying to understand a wireless linux device driver.

So after netdev_open is called...

what happens?

I know packets are being transmitted through an xmit function, but how does the code get there?

Answer (score 0):

The `dev->hard_start_xmit()` function for the netdev is called out of the networking core - see `net/core/dev.c` (in particular `dev_hard_start_xmit()` and `dev_queue_xmit()`).  These functions are in turn called out from the protocol handlers - see for example `ip_queue_xmit()` in `net/ipv4/ip_output.c`.